# Why are billing and delivery address fields required to setup SagePay transactions?

Tags: opayo

As the title says, i have some questions about the mandatory valies required to register a server integration transaction.

**Questions**

1. Why are Billing Address fields and Delivery address fields required since protocol version 2.23? (seems odd as the transaction is for payment of a service already provided/delivered)
2. Is there an alternative SagePay integration method that could be used to avoid having to provide these fields?

**Quick background about integration requirement**

I'm developing a Website bill payment Gateway for 'Client A'. Their customers is sent paper invoices and will have the option to pay their bill online. The customer will enter their bill details and a lookup to a web service provided by 'Client A' will return a bill and bill total.

I will then allow the customer to review their bill and choose to pay their bill via SagePay. When the customer chooses to pay their bill, i was intending to register the transaction with SagePay by sending the fields (VendorTxCode as the bill ID) and the Total of the bill.

'Client A' would then produce a report of successful SagePay transactions and match the (VendorTxCode as the bill ID) to their system to mark the payment as complete.

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a SagePay token but you must send this information over the wire on the first hit and subsequently you can use the token it provides you back.