# Why is the Delivery Address mandatory in SagePay v3.0?

Tags: opayo

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116464/why-are-billing-and-delivery-address-fields-required-to-setup-sagepay-transactio), which didn't have a suitable answer (basically recommends tokenisation). I'm intrigued as to why the fields for delivery address are mandatory as I'm assuming this isn't validated against. The billing address makes sense as this will be the address linked to the card and therefore worth validating. However, the delivery address presumably provides very little.

I can see that it's provided in the response from SagePay in relation to PayPal payments, presumably to check whether this has been altered when getting to PayPal, but as PayPal payments are optional, then if this is the only reason surely it too should be optional?

The reason I ask is that when providing a service rather than a tangible physical product, what should go in this? I'm assuming in most cases this would simply be the same as the billing address, but in the scenario that a 3rd party pays for the service, should the delivery address now be the address of the person receiving the service?

Comment: You'll probably have to ask Sage why, we can't really answer this.

Comment: @DavidG - I thought that might be the case, but as our relationship is run through the business and it therefore takes longer, I was hoping to get an answer from someone who's asked Sage this already.

Comment: Just email `support@sagepay.com`, they're pretty good at responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fraud screening. Sage Pay send all of that stuff to a third party, which then provides a fraud score.

Some of the criteria for that fraud score are based around delivery (known dodgy addresses, business rather than residential, delivery address doesn't match billing etc).

You can just submit billing addresses - you may have to tune your approach towards fraud scores accordingly.